# Minus, Plus, Times, Exponentiation?

Tags: code-golf, math

This is a CMC (chat mini challenge) that I posted in our chatroom, [The Ninteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), a bit ago.

#### The Challenge

Given a positive integer `x`, depending on the last 2 bits of `x`, do the following:

```
x & 3 == 0: 0
x & 3 == 1: x + x
x & 3 == 2: x * x
x & 3 == 3: x ^ x (exponentiation)
```

#### Input/Output

```
Single Integer -> Single Integer
```

A trailing newline is permitted in the output. No other whitespace is permitted.

#### Testcases

```
input       output
    1            2
    2            4
    3           27
    4            0
    5           10
    6           36
    7       823543
    8            0
    9           18
   10          100
   11 285311670611
   12            0
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest code wins!

Comment: Shouldn't the `0` case be `x + 2`, seeing as how the others are `x * 2`, `x ^ 2`, and `x ^^ 2` (tetration)? :P

Comment: What is the largest output we should support (regarding `x ^ x`)? 32-bit is already not enough for test case `11`, and 64-bit is not enough for test case `19`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I will say that you only have to handle cases where the input and output are in the scope of your language, as long as your program would theoretically work given infinite number size.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Ok, in that case I've fixed my (Java 7) code (for +72 bytes.. xD)

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ị“+×*_”v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wd/ejhjnah6drxT9qmFv239AoSOdwu8qjpjXu/wE)

### How it works

Firstly, notice that `x&3` is equivalent to `x%4`, where `%` is modulo. Then, since Jelly uses modular indexing (`a[n] == a[n+len(a)]`), so we don't even need to deal with that.

Then:

- If `x%4==0`, return `x_x` (subtraction) (for consistency);
- If `x%4==1`, return `x+x`;
- If `x%4==2`, return `x×x`(multiplication);
- If `x%4==3`, return `x*x`(exponentiation)

Note that Jelly uses 1-indexing, so the subtraction `"_"` is moved to the end.

```
ị“+×*_”v  example input: 10
ị“+×*_”   index 10 of the string “+×*_”, which gives "×"
       v  evaluate the above as a Jelly expression,
          with 10 as the argument, meaning "10×" is the
          expression evaluated. The dyad "×" takes the
          second argument from the only argument, effectively
          performing the function to itself.
```

Comment: @andrybak AFAIK Jelly has its own encoding - see [here](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), but I do know that all of its characters are 1 byte.

Comment: "8 bytes". How should bytes be counted? This answer consists of eight characters, but at least in the encoding stackexchange serves this page, it takes up 15 bytes (counted using `wc --bytes`).

Comment: If the language interprets it in one encoding, it doesn't make sense to use another encoding for the byte count (imo)

Comment: @andrybak The code encoded in an encoding so that the browser shows it correctly is 15 bytes. The code in an encoding that Jelly understands it is 8 bytes. Look at https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page if you want to know how it is encoded.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 30 bytes

```python
lambda x:[0,x+x,x*x,x**x][x%4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQYRVtoFOhXaFToQXCWhWx0RWqJrH/C4oy80o00jRAZGZeQWmJhiYQ/DcGAA)

Comment: Alternative version on python 2: 'lambda x:[0,2,x,x**x/x][x%4]*x'.

Answer (score 9):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
ri__"-+*#"=~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UGR@vpKutpaxkW/f/vwUA)

#### Explanation

```
ri            e# Read an int from input (call it x).
  __          e# Duplicate x twice.
    "-+*#"    e# Push this string.
          =   e# Get the character from the string at index x (mod 4).
           ~  e# Eval that char, using the two copies of x from before.
```

Runs one of the following operations depending on `x`'s value mod 4 (mod 4 is equivalent to AND 3).

```
0:  -  Subtraction
1:  +  Addition
2:  *  Multiplication
3:  #  Exponentiation
```

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica 25 Bytes

```
0[2#,#*#,#^#][[#~Mod~4]]&
```

Saved 4 Bytes thanks to @MartinEnder

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
.v@"0y*^
```

[Interpreter](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=.v%40%220y%2a%5E&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12)

Comment: Yes I have tested this and it works. And no, I can't use `v` instead of `.v`.

Comment: I thought the scope was local... I thought `.v` cannot access `Q`... Apparently I got outgolfed in Pyth. +1 for you.

Comment: @LeakyNun No it's `v` which has local scope, `.v` just evals an expression.

Comment: I have much to learn...

Comment: @LeakyNun You *do* have much to learn. Also, Pyth is almost as confusing as Jelly, so I forgive that :)

Comment: That's beautiful! That's absolutely amazing! I had no idea that was even possible. For style points, `"0y*^` could be `"-+*^`.

Comment: @isaacg So you didn't implement `.v`, right? And I purposefully chose the former because I don't see any reason to do x-x instead of 0 or x+x instead of x*2.

Comment: Lol guys why are you acting like WOW WHOA WTF? I just don't get it at all...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I implemented `.v`. I hadn't realized that when I implemented auto-variable introduction that it allow `.v` to handle this sort of case. Note for instance that [this](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.v%5C%2B&input=2&debug=0) fails, because while `.v` autointroduces variables, it doesn't take input. The fact that `Q` had already been instantiated by the modular indexing is essential to making this work.

Comment: @isaacg Yeah I get it, it does indeed run in a local scope then.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
->x{x*[0,2,x,x**~-x][x%4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7P9r2tXUV2hFW2gY6RToVOhpVWnWxEbXaFqElv7X8NQT8/QSFMvN7GguqaipkAhLboCKAwA)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 37 Bytes

```php
<?=[0,2*$x=$argn,$x*$x,$x**$x][$x&3];
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/992a252296d9bddff362ea213f918c004681c1dc)

## PHP, 47 Bytes

```php
<?=(bc.[sub,add,mul,pow][($x=$argn)&3])($x,$x);
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29748e1a3da588d1988e55ed9d82273b2a6969e5)

[BC Math functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
f x=cycle[0,x+x,x*x,x^x]!!x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwja5MjknNdpAp0K7QqdCC4jjKmIVFSv@5yZm5inYKhQUZeaVKKgo5CYWKKQpRBvq6Rkaxf4HAA)

Edit: Thanks to @Ørjan Johansen for 1 byte.

Comment: Hm I'm very late, but you could shorten this a byte with `cycle`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: better late than never. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 24 bytes

```javascript
a=>[0,a+a,a*a,a**a][a%4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#S7P9n2hrF22gk6idqJOoBcJaibHRiaomsf@T8/OK83NS9XLy0zXSNCw0Na25UIUsMYUMDbCIGQLF/gMA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 75 bytes

```
long c(int n){int x=n%4;return x<1?0:x<2?n+n:x<3?n*n:(long)Math.pow(n,n);}
```

Even though it is valid according to the rules, `long` is 64-bits, so it fails for the exponentiation test cases of `19^19` and above. To fix that we can use a `BigDecimal` approach:

**<s>148</s> 146 bytes**

```
import java.math.*;BigDecimal c(int n){int x=n%4;BigDecimal m=new BigDecimal(n);return x<1?m.subtract(m):x<2?m.add(m):x<3?m.multiply(m):m.pow(n);}
```

**Explanation (of BigDecimal approach):**

```
import java.math.*;                // Import required for BigDecimal
BigDecimal c(int n){               // Method with integer parameter and BigDecimal return-type
  int x=n%4;                       //  Input modulo-4
  BigDecimal m=new BigDecimal(n);  //  Convert input integer to BigDecimal
  return x<1?                      //  If the input mod-4 is 0:
    m.subtract(m)                  //   Return input - input (shorter than BigDecimal.ZERO)
   :x<2?                           //  Else if the input mod-4 is 1:
    m.add(m)                       //   Return input + input
   :x<3?                           //  Else if the input mod-4 is 2:
    m.multiply(m)                  //   Return input * input
   :                               //  Else:
    m.pow(n);                      //   Return input ^ input
}                                  // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#TU9BasMwELz7FUOgINUgSNpeKptC6bWnHEsPiuwmKl5ZyKvEIfjtrpwU2sMyO7PDMOso9JHxbY5GkeGDuteF7cww4P1SAAMbdhbzq9u/tdaR6WCF8wwvLwuMtb971P@uVPv2hD9BeKljyyl6jNX6hdSQdhyNZUHyeaw2WTFNcyMPmVDq2IXuvCikQn9aAqYZCGnX5Sa/hY69a0DGebHl6Pz@4xNGLoWBrz7iWtGhxlpnqGpsnvJSlhI3D7A9D9yS6hOrkANY5LckSqw0VlJfTVOxzDT/AA)

```
import java.math.*;
class M{
  static BigDecimal c(int n){int x=n%4;BigDecimal m=new BigDecimal(n);return x<1?m.subtract(m):x<2?m.add(m):x<3?m.multiply(m):m.pow(n);}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
      System.out.print(c(i) + "; ");
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2; 4; 27; 0; 10; 36; 823543; 0; 18; 100; 285311670611; 0; 26; 196; 437893890380859375; 0; 34; 324; 1978419655660313589123979; 0; 42; 484; 20880467999847912034355032910567; 0; 50;
```

Comment: You don't need to fix the program this way :P The old answer would work if numbers had infinite size; the first program would have been valid under my specs. :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Then I specify that in the answer.. Ah well, Java won't win any code-golf challenges anyway. ;)

Comment: Yes, I would specify. And yes, it's Java, it's not going to win. :D

Comment: "_And yes, it's Java, it's not going to win. :D_" I'm used to it. :P Even [my shortest Java answer ever of 8 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113448/is-this-even-or-odd/113451#113451) is way to long compared to the golfing answers. xD Although it was the first time I had beaten a Python answer with my Java answer, which has to count for something I guess. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 63 or 62 bytes

```
#include<math.h>
f(x){return(int[]){0,x+x,x*x,pow(x,x)}[x&3];}
```

-1 byte if macros are allowed, assuming `x` is not an expression like `3+5` (since that'd mess up the precedence):

```
#include<math.h>
#define f(x)(int[]){0,x+x,x*x,pow(x,x)}[x&3]
```

Comment: @ceilingcat Right, forgot about that.

Comment: does not compile on MSVS2015; Intellisense said `cast to incomplete array type "int[]" is not allowed` Compiler said `error C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax`; ALSO! where is int f(int x)? code is actually at least 8 bytes longer; also it is very slow and inefficient, as it evaluates everytning - dont repeat it IRL)

Comment: @xakepp35 What? 1) it has to compile in *a* C compiler. Most (read: just about all but MSVC) C compilers support this `(int[])` syntax for this situation. 2) `f(x)` is perfectly legal C89. I didn't specify the standard. 3) This is about code size, not efficiency. And 4) If you're going to be patronizing, at least use a real compiler and/or check your facts.

Comment: @Tim Čas Ah yes, rly sorry! I was trying to compile it as C++ code. That's my fault) It compiles and works great!

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 39 bytes

```
x=>new[]{0,2,x,Math.Pow(x,x-1)}[x&3]*x;
```

#### Explanation

Observe that:

(x-x, x+x, x*x, x^x) == (0, 2, x, x^(x-1)) * x

The solution creates an array, indexes into it and then multiplies the result by `x`:

```
x => new[] { 0, 2, x, Math.Pow(x,x-1) }[x&3] * x;
```

#### Alternative versions:

```
x=>new[]{0,x+x,x*x,Math.Pow(x,x)}[x%4];
```

(39B, all multiplication done in the array, `x%4` replaces `x&3`)

```
x=>x%4<2?x%2*2*x:Math.Pow(x,x%4<3?2:x);
```

(39B, same as @MetaColon's answer but `x%2*2*x` replacing `x*x%4<1?0:2`)

Answer (score 2):

### x86 Assembler, Intel syntax, 192 bytes

```
.data
f dw @q,@w,@e,@r
.code
mov ecx, eax
and ecx, 3
mov edx,dword ptr f[ecx*4]
call [edx]
ret
q:
xor eax,eax
ret
w:
add eax,eax
ret
e:
mul eax,eax
ret
r:
mov ecx,eax
t:
mul eax,eax
loop t
ret
```

Example pretends for fastest working speed. Is is a program or program part, which uses fastcall convention. It assumes input variable `x` in register `eax`, and returns result also in `eax`. Basic idea is stay away from using conditional jumps, as in some examples here. Also, it is not to evaluate everything (as in C example with arrays) but to use array of pointers to functons and make faster unconditional jumps (jmp/call) as an optimized "C language switch()-case.." analog. This technique could be also useful in kinds of finita automata - like processor emulators, executors and so on.

Upd: for x64 use "r" in register names, instead of "e" (e.g. `rax` instead of `eax`, `rcx` instead of `ecx`). Size will not be changed, and it will use 64-bit unsigned words.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The objective of this challenge is to make your code as short as possible. In this case, your code could easily be shortened a bunch by combining all those function declarations. You can also remove some whitespace.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino asm itself is kinda "long" language :) so i dont have an idea on how to make this shorter. any example-advices?

Comment: Eh, sorry, I must have copied my comment on your C answer into this post. I don't know how to program in ASM but could you potentially remove some whitespace?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino, sorry.. but seems no) it has to be longest code among others, i can just trunc windows crlf to linux format so 209->192 bytes, changes are not visible)

Comment: Aw. That's too bad. But nice submission regardless! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 12 bytes

```
;;3&"-+*ⁿ"Eƒ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@29tbaympKut9ahxv5LrsUn//xsDAA)

Explanation:

```
;;3&"-+*ⁿ"Eƒ
;;            two copies of input (so 3 total)
  3&          bitwise AND with 3
    "-+*ⁿ"E   index into this string
           ƒ  call the respective function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
Ð"-+*m"è.V
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394gpKutlau0uEVemH//5sCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
4&|{0,+:,*:,^~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@59ma2WiVlNtoKNtpaNlpRNX9z81OSNfIU3JQMHOyiFTT8HQqIIrtSKz5D8A)

Comment: `(4&|{-,+,*,^)~` works as well but it's the same byte count due to parens, although it's slightly more obvious what it does.

Answer (score 1):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 25 bytes

```
mn4%3Q*nkn4%2Q*nxn4%1Q*++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/oasis#@5@bZ6JqHKiVlw2kjYB0BZA2DNTS1v7//7@hIQA)

### How it works

Notice that `x&3` is equivalent to `x%4`, where `%` is modulo.

```
mn4%3Q*nkn4%2Q*nxn4%1Q*++  input is n
mn4%3Q*                    (n**n)*((n%4)==3)
       nkn4%2Q*            (n**2)*((n%4)==2)
               nxn4%1Q*    (n*2)*((n%4)==1)
                       +   add the above two
                        +  add the above two
```

Oasis is a stack-based language where every character is a command.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 42 Bytes

```cs
x=>x%4<2?x*x%4<1?0:2:Math.Pow(x,x%4<3?2:x)
```

Actually it's normal C#, but as you can't run it as a whole program and you have to type it into the interactive, I guess you may call it *C# interactive*.

**Explanation**:

```cs
x => (x % 4) < 2     //If the bits are smaller than 2 (1 or 0)
? x *           //multiply x with
    (x % 4) < 1 //if the bits are 0
    ? 0         //0 (results in 0)
    : 2         //or else with 2 (results in 2*x or x+x)
: Math.Pow(x,   //otherwise power x by
    (x % 4) < 3 //if the bits are 2
    ? 2         //2 (results in x^2 or x*x)
    : x);       //or else x (results in x^x)
```

I can't tell wether it's the shortest variant, any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that's valid. You generally should [submit a program or function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet). Snippets are not allowed by default.

Comment: @Cyoce It is a program. You just have to run it through the interactive, which will interpret the program.

Comment: When I run this in interactive, I get an error because `x` is not defined. That makes this a snippet, not a full program.

Comment: @Cyoce In the challenge it said, there'd be a variable x defined.

Comment: That's not what that means. "Given a positive integer `x`" means that you are being *given* `x` through a standard input method (i.e., function or program).

Comment: Just add `x=>` to the start of the submission and you're fine.

Comment: Also, you can call it C# instead of C# Interactive. Function submissions don't require any enclosing class or other boilerplate (except the function declaration, which you have included)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 29 bytes

```
.;.O+@.UOI:4%!^s;((?u.^P;<^*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@69nreev7aAX6u9pZaKqGFdsraFhX6oXF2BtE6dl/f@/OQA)

Explanation will be added soon...

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 36 bytes

```
<?=[0,2,$x=$argn,$x**~-$x][$x&3]*$x;
```

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 27

I've never had the occasion to use arrays in dc before:

```
[+]1:r[*]2:r[^]3:r?dd4%;rxp
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S8svUihJLS5JTixOVcjMU6g21NMzNKq1VkjJ51IAguLUEgVdXQUVmBqwYEFRZl5JmoK6arGCrp2COppsanJGPkJIoUYhJVlBN1VB6X@0dqyhVVG0VqwRkIyLNbYqsk9JMVG1Lqoo@K/ElZKfl/ofAA).

Answer (score 1):

### C, 115 bytes

```
#include<math.h>
#define D(K,L)K(x){return L;}
D(q,0)D(w,x+x)D(e,x*x)D(r,pow(x,x))(*g[])()={q,w,e,r};D(f,g[x%4](x))
```

Example is a function `int f(int x)`

It pretends for fastest working speed as it keeps CPU away from using conditional jumps. And this is only correct speed-optimisation way for this task. Also, it tries not to evaluate everything, as in array C example `return(int[]){0,x+x,x*x,pow(x,x)}[x%4];` But but to wisely use array of pointers to functons, in order to make much faster unconditional jumps (jmp/call) with much faster address arithmetics, as an optimized version of "switch()-case..". This technique could be also useful in several kinds of finita automata - like processor emulators, executors, command stream parsers, and so on - where speed matters and code like `switch(x%4) case(0):... case(1):...`  is unsuitable because it produces multiple cmp/jnz instructions; and these are [costly operations for CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor)

Simpliest and shortest test program (in default conditions) for the case will be as follows:

```
D(main,f(x))
```

It will add just 12 bytes of payload and will total our size to 127 bytes;

But you should better tell the linker to use `f` function as an entry point, instead of `main`. That is the way, if we aim to get fastest possible working binary for this task from shortest code ;-) This happens because C library adds extra init/shutdown code before calling your main() function.

Code compiles on MSVS Community 2015 without any tricks and issues and produces correct results. I haven't tested it with gcc, but i'm sure it will work fine as well.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The objective of this challenge is to make your code as short as possible. In this case, your code could easily be shortened a bunch by combining all those function declarations. You can also remove some whitespace.

Comment: I like the idea of using pointers to functions

Comment: @RosLuP ye, but its almost twice longer than your 60 bytes version. but it  works much faster, it is worth its size.

Comment: @Hyper Neutrino Okay. I've compressed it more. Seems, this is final version! There are no bugs, all tests passed 8-)

Comment: @xakepp35 did you measure your is faster than my?

Comment: @RosLuP sure:D for 2147483648 iterations of i=f(i) runtime for your version is 6.98236s, function works with 307.558mhz frequency

Comment: @RosLuP And my version runs only for 3.908s runtime; 549.51mhz; So it is 1.78x faster; Man; Just read on how does branch predictor works; and what happens if prediction was wrong. All "if" are slow as hell!!! If you could avoid using conditional jumps - avoid using it! So, you use x%2? - what is that "?"? how do you think?) Hint - compile two versions and compare their disassembly code!

Comment: @Tim Čas and your version is slowest among us; 10.2782s runtime
208.935mhz; And also RosLuP has shorter version. So he won, both in approach and length; Upvoting his ver, as this is code golf for shortest code ;-)

Comment: I even thought about new computer architecture, where CPU is one chip, with multiple cores, only capable of handling all IFs and tnat kind of conditional execution in a simd like way (and without any ALU). And GPU(ALU) therefore will be a separate chip capable of just doing large scale simd-like maths. But seems to be too lazy and have lack of free milliards of dollars to implement this =)))

Comment: @xakepp35 "2147483648 iterations of i=f(i) runtime for your version is 6.98236s" for me is fast enough;  not are these the problems in slow code... The same jnz jump and loop I not find they slow dow the code too much. The real problem is the code is wrong because from input 11 return wrong results (if I remember well it return a wrong value without some warning to the user of the function)

Comment: @RosLup, it does not matter what is enough for you or me. We told about speed benchmarks and relative comparison., and bad programmer is a programmer that chooses 1.7x slower algorithm just because it is shorter/simplier. Whole PC world lags problems arose from tnat decision motivation. On other hand, you said "enough for you"/ I always leave place for situation, wrere i make mistake/misassumption. So maybe i am wrong.. Lets clear this out! What do you mean? Where exactly do you use current algorithm? And how do you consider is it "enough" or "not enough"? Have you tried some benchmarks?

Comment: @RosLup and for big numbers we could use `int64` or even `double` types, or, even, we could use some kind of bigint (arbitary precision int arithmetics) libraries, if that is really required. but that was not the point.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 26 bytes

```
{x->[0,x+x,x*x,x**x][x%4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/groovy#q1CwVQiuLC5JzdXLzNPLSy0PSk1MSS3S0NQrAjJ8MvNSNTQVEosVMvNKuFJS0xTSFGz/V1fo2kUb6FRoV@hUaIGwVkVsdIWqSWzt/4IioMKcPI00jQpNzf/mAA)

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>47</s> 42 bytes

```
x=scan();c(`-`,`+`,`*`,`^`)[[x%%4+1]](x,x)
```

Applies the function `-`, `+`, `*`, or `^` based on the modulus of `x` to `x` and `x`.

`-` is the only (somewhat) smart thing, since `x-x` is always 0.

## R, 33 bytes

```
pryr::f(c(0,2*x,x^2,x^x)[x%%4+1])
```

Same method as other people use. Though it is shorter, I don't like it nearly as much.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
.vjd,+@"-+*^
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.vjd%2C%2B%40%22-%2B%2a%5E&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12&debug=0)

### How it works

Firstly, notice that `x&3` is equivalent to `x%4`, where `%` is modulo. Then, since Pyth uses modular indexing (`a[n] == a[n+len(a)]`), so we don't even need to deal with that.

Then:

- If `x%4==0`, return `x-x` (for consistency);
- If `x%4==1`, return `x+x`;
- If `x%4==2`, return `x*x`;
- If `x%4==3`, return `x^x`.

---

```
.vjd,+@"-+*^  example input: 10
      @"-+*^  "-+*^"[10], which is "*"
     +        "*10"
    ,         ["*10","10"]
  jd          "*10 10"
.v            evaluate as Pyth expression
              (Pyth uses Polish notation)
```

More about Polish notation: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) (too bad if you are in Turkey).

Comment: Huh? This just seems too much to me. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

```
Ov"^+*p"gU +U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@@9fphSnrVWglB6qoB36/7@hIQA)

This uses the same method as the other eval answers, except the program `-U` just negates `U`, so we use `^` (bitwise XOR) instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Vim, 50 bytes

```
y$o^R"A-+*^^V^[0^R"lx0"_Dp^[0D@"kJ0"ad$:r!echo ^R"^R0|bc^<Enter>
```

Here, `^V` represents a `Ctrl+V`, `^R` represents `Ctrl-R` and `^[` represents the `esc` key

Works by first building up the expression and then letting `bc` evaluate it. Expects the input on the first line in an otherwise empty buffer.

Explanation:

```
y$o^R"                                                          Copies the input into register " and pastes it on the second line
      A-+*^^V^[0^R"lx0"_Dp                                      Enters that text after the input on the second line
                          ^[0D@"                                Executes the second line as a Vim command.
                                                                For example, if the input is 12, the second line would be 12A-+*^^[012lx0"_Dp, which means:
                                                                  12A-+*^^[           Insert the text -+*^ 12 times
                                                                           012lx0"_Dp Go 12 chars to the right and remove everything except for that.
                                                                If effect, this basically just selects the appropriate operation.
                                kJ0"ad$                         Put the operator after the number, cut it into register a
                                       :r!                      Execute the following shell command and put the result into the buffer:
                                          echo ^R"^R0|bc<Enter> The shell command "echo [contents of register a][contents of registers 0]|bc. As said above, register a contains the input and the operator, and register 0 contains the input. The <enter> then executes this command.
```

Comment: When I type `^V` it just pastes what I have in my clipboard, instead of the number...

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@1@pki@k5KirrRUnJm0gpJRTYaAU71IgbeDioJTtZaCUmKJiVaSYmpyRryCkJGRQk5TM9f@/KQA "V – TIO Nexus") Also, You can do `D` instead of `d$`

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
@[0yQ*QQ^
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40%5B0yQ%2aQQ%5E&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12&debug=0)

Nothing fancy going on here, just calculate the four values, and select one with modular indexing.

```
@[0yQ*QQ^
@[0yQ*QQ^QQ)Q    Implicit variable introduction
@           Q    Modularly index into the following list
 [0        )     0
   yQ            Q*2
     *QQ         Q*Q
        ^QQ      Q^Q
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 135 bytes

```
@set/an=%1*2^&6
@goto %n%
:6
@set n=1
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @set/an*=%1
@goto 0
:4
@set n=%1
:2
@set/an*=%1
:0
@echo %n%
```

I was hoping to create the exponentiation by building up and evaluating a string of the form `[0+...+0, 2+...+2, x+...+x, x*...*x]` depending on the last two bits of `x` but unfortunately the code to select the operation took too long to express because I couldn't use `*` as a `for` parameter, but I was at least able to use some fall-though trickery to golf away some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 87 bytes

```
.+
$*1;$&$*
;((1111)*)(1?)$
;$3$3
1(?=1.*;((1111)*111)$)
$1;
+`\G1(?=.*;(1*))|;1*$
$1
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#PckxEkBAEETRvM/R1MyoUtoimVJClxA4iLsvm/jBT15n513HAQwlewbSTF8ebjqcSBYWyI5dY/zYRgeVGO7rbNxU4f6kgp9AtU4QZhQsWLG9) (Link includes test suite.)

Explanation: The first two lines convert the input into unary and duplicate it (so we now have `x;x`). The next two lines look for an `x&3` of either `0` or `1` and change `x;x` into `x;0` or `x;2` appropriately. The next two lines look for `x&3==3` and change `x;x` into `x;x;x;...;x;1;x` (`x` `x`s). This means that we have either `x;0`, `x;2`, `x;x`, or `x;...;x` and it remains to multiply everything together and convert back to decimal. (The multiplication code is based on that in the Retina wiki but amended to handle multiplication by zero.)

Answer (score 0):

### vba, 101

```
Function x(f)
Select Case f Mod 4
Case 0:x=0
Case 1:x=f+f
Case 2:x=f*f
Case 3:x=f ^f
End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyvil](https://github.com/dyvil/dyvil/), 24 Bytes

```
x=>[0,x+x,x*x,x**x][x&3]
```

**Usage**:

```
let f: int->int = x=>[0,x+x,x*x,x**x][x&3]
print f(10) // => 100
```

**Explanation**:

The code creates a lambda expression that takes and returns a 32-bit integer. The body stores the result of all calculations in an array and retrieves the result from the index given by the last 2 bits of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, <s>105</s> <s>68</s> 67 bytes

Here is the body of the function:

```
i in let a=i%4;return [0,i+i,i*i,Int(pow(Double(i),Double(i)))][a]
```

Here is the full implementation:

```
import Foundation;var e:(Int)->Int={i in let a=i%4;return [0,i+i,i*i,Int(pow(Double(i),Double(i)))][a]}
```

Try it [here](https://iswift.org/playground?4YoLc9)

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, <s>27</s>, 23 bytes

```
:Prompt X          //Get input as X, 3 bytes
:{2X,X²,X^X,0      //Implicitly store the list {2X,X²,X^X,0} to Ans, 16 bytes
:Ans(remainder(X,4 //Compute X&3 (as X%4), get that element of the list, and implicitly print 8 bytes
```

TI-BASIC doesn't have bitwise operators, so I used the modulus operator (`remainder(`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

## oK, 20 bytes

```
{*/(."-+*#"4!x).x,x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#uqICt)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 59 bytes

```
#include<math.h>
h(x){return x&2?pow(x,x&1?x:2):(x&1)*2*x;}
```

Test and results. It overflows at 11.

```
main()
{int i;
 for(i=0;i<20;++i)
       printf("%u %u\n", i, h(i));
}

0 0
1 2
2 4
3 27
4 0
5 10
6 36
7 823543
8 0
9 18
10 100
11 1843829075
12 0
13 26
14 196
15 1500973039
16 0
17 34
18 324
19 0
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/4eI270)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#JcpBDoIwEEDR/ZxigoF0AA12SVEu4oYg2ElKIZXGJoSrW0n8q7f48cS2N/45NFO36ou@gxaBNjes3lkMmWyX@SNCGbJrG2pJtThEucyD2iFOHVtBsLFdkRXgODvBt0pxIytVFEyA/xZ3LKNIUo@pf9ikRC5RCyZSsAPEbz@a7vWOZzP9AA)

Comment: Why someone  downvote this?

Comment: does not compile.int main(); int h(int x) please!

Comment: @xakepp35 here http://ideone.com/4eI270 it compile; if it is for arguments of function, in a old standard they are seen from compiler all as int...

Comment: In "tio" gcc compier not compile even this: #include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double h(int x){return x&2?pow((double)x,(double)(x&1?x:2)):(double)((x&1)*2*x);}; it says the linker not find the pow function (double pow(double, double) in math.h header)

Comment: The trick it is to add "-lm" [link math functions] to the line compiler is called

Comment: but its actually 68 bytes, ok?)

Comment: latest MSVS community dont compile without types

Comment: @xakepp35 "msvs" compiler has to have the option for compile ANSI or K&R C code... In filename.c  gcc and bcc compile it show only some warning for the name of functions library have no type declaration or equivalent...

Answer (score 0):

## Pure Bash, 35

```bash
a=(- + * **)
echo $[$1${a[$1%4]}$1]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#RYoxCoAwEAR7X7HFSTQSIWIn@hGxCOZEm0RMOvHtUQRxiylmdvEHIoc4m8DYHE5d17q5Olif4VngCKVA3@eV@7G5uEDkAWqA@GsyfaFQQULKMuN59aCRNJ3mYd5OF@kpWe843Q).

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, <s>59</s> 33 bytes

```
h(x)==[0,x+x,x*x,x^x].(1+x rem 4)
```

traslate in Axiom the answer of Mego... this is the old 59 bytes

```
h(x)==(x quo 2 rem 2=1=>(x rem 2=0=>x^2;x^x);(x rem 2)*2*x)
```

results

```
(24) -> for i in 0..30 repeat output [i,h(i)]
   [0,0]
   [1,2]
   [2,4]
   [3,27]
   [4,0]
   [5,10]
   [6,36]
   [7,823543]
   [8,0]
   [9,18]
   [10,100]
   [11,285311670611]
   [12,0]
   [13,26]
   [14,196]
   [15,437893890380859375]
   [16,0]
   [17,34]
   [18,324]
   [19,1978419655660313589123979]
   [20,0]
   [21,42]
   [22,484]
   [23,20880467999847912034355032910567]
   [24,0]
   [25,50]
   [26,676]
   [27,443426488243037769948249630619149892803]
   [28,0]
```