# iHateOddNumbers

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, integer, error-message

## Task

Given a non-negative number, check if it's odd or even. In case it's even, output that number. Otherwise, throw any exception/error that your language supports, and stop the program.

## Example with Python

Input: `1`
Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".code.tio", line 1, in <module>
    IfYouWantThenThrowThis
NameError: name 'IfYouWantThenThrowThis' is not defined
```

## Another example

Input: `2`
Output: `2`

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with shortest bytes wins.
- [These](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) loopholes are, obviously, forbidden.
- Standard code-golf rules apply.
- Please specify the language you are using and the amount of bytes.
- It would be great if you would put a link to a sandbox where your code can be ran in action, such as [TIO](https://tio.run).
- Explaining your code is very welcomed.

---

## LEADERBOARD

```html
<script>var QUESTION_ID=229052,OVERRIDE_USER=0;</script><style>body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}</style><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;function answersUrl(d){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(d,e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+e.join(";")+"/comments?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){answers.push.apply(answers,d.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],d.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var f=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(f),answers_hash[f]=e}),d.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){d.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),d.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=function(){var d=String.raw`h\d`,e=String.raw`\-?\d+\.?\d*`,f=String.raw`[^\n<>]*`,g=String.raw`<s>${f}</s>|<strike>${f}</strike>|<del>${f}</del>`,h=String.raw`[^\n\d<>]*`,j=String.raw`<[^\n<>]+>`;return new RegExp(String.raw`<${d}>`+String.raw`\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?`+String.raw`(${e})`+String.raw`(?=`+String.raw`${h}`+String.raw`(?:(?:${g}|${j})${h})*`+String.raw`</${d}>`+String.raw`)`)}(),OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;function getAuthorName(d){return d.owner.display_name}function process(){var d=[];answers.forEach(function(n){var o=n.body;n.comments.forEach(function(q){OVERRIDE_REG.test(q.body)&&(o="<h1>"+q.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var p=o.match(SCORE_REG);p&&d.push({user:getAuthorName(n),size:+p[2],language:p[1],link:n.share_link})}),d.sort(function(n,o){var p=n.size,q=o.size;return p-q});var e={},f=1,g=null,h=1;d.forEach(function(n){n.size!=g&&(h=f),g=n.size,++f;var o=jQuery("#answer-template").html();o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",h+".").replace("{{NAME}}",n.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",n.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",n.size).replace("{{LINK}}",n.link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o);var p=n.language;p=jQuery("<i>"+n.language+"</i>").text().toLowerCase(),e[p]=e[p]||{lang:n.language,user:n.user,size:n.size,link:n.link,uniq:p}});var j=[];for(var k in e)e.hasOwnProperty(k)&&j.push(e[k]);j.sort(function(n,o){return n.uniq>o.uniq?1:n.uniq<o.uniq?-1:0});for(var l=0;l<j.length;++l){var m=jQuery("#language-template").html(),k=j[l];m=m.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",k.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",k.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",k.size).replace("{{LINK}}",k.link),m=jQuery(m),jQuery("#languages").append(m)}}</script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/primary.css?v=f52df912b654"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: I would highly recommend you start posting your challenge ideas to the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) first to get feedback

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113448/is-this-even-or-odd)

Comment: I would advise against adding a leaderboard to your challenge, especially one that has to be updated manually, since it takes up space and will likely become outdated soon.

Comment: Is it acceptable to throw an error after outputting the even number, or should errors only be thrown on odd inputs?

Comment: What do you mean? The error is only thrown if the number is odd, and that's the only output you get. As for even numbers, no errors must occur and the output is the number.

Comment: If you really want a leaderboard, I would recommend using [the leaderboard stack snippet](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet) instead. It'll update automatically, so you won't have to edit your question every time someone posts an answer that makes it to the leaderboard.

Comment: I would also advise against having any kind of leaderboard. My answer may be the shortest (and the earliest to be that short), but that doesn't make it any more deserving of attention than any other answer. Personally, I found the Hexagony answer really interesting, along with a number of other answers. Instead, I suggest that people just sort by active - you'll find the creative answers that have been "buried" due to votes that way :)

Comment: So what you're saying is, I _can_ even with this right now?

Comment: I would recommend adding the clarification about the even input having no error, since that is not clear in the actual question

Comment: @JoKing read the 5th comment.

Comment: Yes, but that's not in the question itself, and is easily missed when there's multiple comments. See this [highly upvoted meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8112/76162) for advice to edit it into the question itself

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
MḂ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/34Y6mQwv///9vBAA) (even) and [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/34Y6mQwv///9vDAA) (odd)

### How it works

`M` is an atom meaning "Given a list, yield the indices of that maximal elements". Now, typically, when given integer arguments to its array functions, Jelly promotes them to either a range, to digits, or just wraps it. Unfortunately, (I'm guessing due to `M`'s age - it was one of the earliest builtins in Jelly), `M` doesn't do this, and throws an error as it can't iterate over an integer.

How the code actually works:

```
MḂ¡ - Main link. Takes N on the left
 Ḃ  - Bit; Calculate N % 2
  ¡ - Do the following a number of times equal to N % 2:
M   -   Run the M builtin on N
```

If the input `N` is even, then `Ḃ` yields `0` and `¡` runs `M` on `N` `0` times i.e. an identity function.

If the input is odd, then `Ḃ` yields `1` and `¡` runs `M` once, which is enough to error it

Answer (score 37):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 16 bytes

```python
lambda n:n<<n%-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKs/GJk9VFyiYX6SQp5CZpxBtqGOkY6xjomMaa8WlUFCUmVeikKfDpVBSVAnkQwXSNPI0uRRSK5JTC0oUwhJzSlNdi4ryixAKlMB8Ja7/AA)

The expression `n%-2` equals 0 for even `n` and -1 for odd `n`. Bit-shifting `n` by 0 positions leaves it unchanged, but for -1 positions it gives an error for "negative shift count".

Answer (score 26):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 13 bytes

```
?#\.@!:.!_@\|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/99eOUbPQdFKTzHeIabm/38LS0MjY3MTC0tjE0MLI0tjU3NDC0ugiKkFUNzS3ATMAzEtoOrAFIRnClUJAA)

Expanded: (Made using [Hexagony Colorer](https://github.com/Timwi/HexagonyColorer))

[image: Hexagony Colorer Map]

This code is built around Hexagony's `#` operator. Hexagony initializes with 6 IP's, 1 in each corner of the code box, with the 0th one, the one in the top left, being active in the beginning. The `#` operator takes the value of the current memory cell mod 6, and then sets the corresponding IP as the active one. So making an even/odd checker is a matter of using the `#` operator and then having IP's 1,3, and 5 perform the 'odd' action, and IP's 0,2, and 4 perform the 'even' action. The consequence of doing it this way is that there are 6 separate paths that each need to be mapped to the correct endpoint, hence the mess of paths. In this case, the odd action is `:` (attempt to divide two non-existent values, resulting in a divide by zero error) and the even action is `!@` (print and terminate). To make it hopefully a bit more readable, here's a very low-tech drawing of the paths:

[image: Hand-drawn map]

The paths are:

- n%6 == 0 : Green
- n%6 == 1 : Yellow
- n%6 == 2 : Blue
- n%6 == 3 Pink
- n%6 == 4 : Orange
- n%6 == 5 : Red

I'm pretty confident 12 bytes is possible, and potentially even shorter. Not sure if there's a better approach entirely, but with this method, it seems just about brute-force-able. It seems it should only require `?`,`#`, no more than 3 each of `@`,`!`, and `:`, and some control flow characters.

Comment: Hand-drawn Hexagony execution map is a great evolution path from hand-drawn circles

Answer (score 16):

## x86 Machine Code, 5 bytes

```
A8 01 74 01 F4
```

Takes the integer value of your choice in the `EAX` register, halts the CPU if the number is odd, or continues execution harmlessly if the number is even.

Ungolfed assembly language mnemonics:

```
A8 01         test   al, 1
74 01         jz     IsEven
F4            hlt
          IsEven:
```

The first two instructions (`test`+`jz`) are the fastest and smallest way to check whether an integer value is even or odd in x86 machine code. The reason they work is hopefully obvious: for binary numbers, the least-significant bit (bit 0) is only set if the number is odd (for even numbers, the least-significant bit is clear). Therefore, testing the least-significant bit and seeing if it is non-zero is the easiest, simplest, smallest, and fastest way to see whether a number is even.

Here, I've used `jz` to jump if the zero flag (ZF) is set—i.e., if the bit we tested (bit 0) was zero, which means that it jumps if the number was even. Note that it jumps *over* the halt (`hlt`) instruction if the input value was even. If the input value was odd, then execution falls through the jump, and ends up halting the CPU.

If you don't like `hlt` because you don't think that counts as throwing an exception/error, then replace it with an `int 3` instruction, which is also only 1 byte (`0xCC`), and thus doesn't change the overall code size (5 bytes). The `int 3` instruction is the trap to a debugger.

The only way you could really argue that this code is cheating is that it doesn't "output" that number. I'd say it does: it allows execution to continue past the point where that number was generated, which is a lot like outputting it. You don't get any output for odd inputs; you can only get output for even inputs. Besides that, I think this is allowed by many, many different [agreed-upon input/output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447).

---

## x86 Machine Code, 6 bytes (non-competing)

A division by 0 is another obvious solution, but it doesn't save any bytes. Even if you are willing to allow clobbering the input value, in order to arrange for a division by zero, you have to negate somewhere (either the original value, or the isolated LSB), and that requires an extra instruction (either `XOR`ing with 1, or a `NOT`), which means 2 extra bytes.

```
A8 01         test   al, 1
34 01         xor    al, 1
F6 F0         div    al
```

That's 6 bytes, and I'm not even sure that I can figure out how to justify this clobbering of the original input value as being consistent with the requirements of the challenge to "output" the value.

To avoid clobbering, there are a few different options. For example, we can stipulate that the input is taken in a different register (say, `ECX`). But this means that we can't use the short "implied accumulator" encoding of `test` and `xor`, so it costs us at least two bytes. (We could use `not` with the full register before the `test` to invert the bits, which is encoded in only 2 bytes, but that defeats the point, which is to avoid clobbering the input.) Or, we could `push` and `pop` the input, but that also costs two extra bytes (one for each, `push` and `pop`). Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not seeing a better solution here.

Comment: It could be argued that the 2 byte `test al,1` (where output is in `ax` if even and `nz` flag if odd) would meet the requirements, since testing for a flag is a very standard way in machine code to signify an "exception/error".

Comment: You can save a byte by switching the `jz isEven` to a `jnz -3` : that is, jumping into the middle of the `test al, 1` instruction. The byte sequence `01 74 01` does not correspond to a valid x86 instruction encoding so you will get SIGILL.

Comment: oh my god what the is going on here

Comment: If possible, please make a link to the language origin/wiki page, and very much preferably an online implementation of this. If second is impossible, then tell me

Comment: @Leopard What is a "language origin/wiki page"? x86 is an extremely popular microprocessor architecture originally developed by Intel. I call it "machine code" because of weird code-golf rules about byte counting. Normally, people would just call this assembly, but that would apparently mean that I have to count the ASCII characters in the assembly mnemonics, which is ridiculous. You'll note that I usually include a link to "Try It Online" for my assembly answers, but that's not really possible here. You won't be able to tell that the CPU is halted. I feel like the explanation is sufficient.

Comment: That's fantastic, @Sisyphus! I don't know why I didn't think of that. Feel free to edit, or post your own competing answer.

Comment: Reminds me of the good old M68000 where a single `tst (a0)` (two bytes) would be sufficient, as it crashes when using odd addresses. Unfortunately, newer CPUs of this family support odd addresses…

Comment: @CodyGray by "language origin/wiki page" I mean a page where they tell us about the machine code (or the assembly), that was needed to make a leaderboard link (which isn't necessary now). And about the online implementation, thanks for explaining

Comment: Yes, leaving a value in a register is acceptable, so you don't need to justify it as not cheating since we have a meta page on acceptable assembly conventions. It's effectively a custom calling convention right

Comment: I don't remember if assembly has to have a return call or not, I think not

Answer (score 15):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 10 bytes

```java
n->n/=~n&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVA9T8MwEN3zK54qBTmUGMrYECQGBoaKoWJCDK7jBIfEtuxLRYTKXw8mohUDYrl7p/dxp2vFXuRt9Tbp3llPaOPMB9IdrwcjSVvDz4tEdiIEbIQ2@EgAN@w6LRFIUGx7qyv0kWNb8to0zy8QvgnZLAUeDD0Z4cdHp7wg61GjnEx@ay7LT3O2mopZVUeCaUPQKJGvrooIbkrMYLk8ZgHbMZDquR2Iu7iMarZIr6s1FhfQWfEjIj@eDH9bqtRER82Fc914F@KNTGcn/wFSkHwFu3@Xyn0/ASr7P1F5b/0aaZiDFW8UbVQIolHsV25yrIfkMH0B)

### Explanations

This code basically divides by zero when the input number is odd or by one when it is even.

#### `~n`

The `~` character negates each bit of `n` because `n&1` returns `0` when `n` is even and `1` when it's odd, but we want the opposite: `0` when odd (to make it fail) and `1` when even to return it, so `~` is the easiest way to negate the last bit.

#### `~n&1`

This is the part that reduces `n` to either `0` or `1`. `~n&1` is not exactly the same as `~n%2` because, in Java, `%2` keeps the signum of `n`, and since we definitely swap the signum with `~`, we'd always end up with negative number, not matter what `n` is: if `n<0` we'd get negative divided by positive, and if `n>=0`, we'd get positive divided by negative.

We want to divide by `0` or by `1`, nothing else. Only `&1` can guarantee that. No matter what, the operator priority will first evaluate `~n` so no parenthesis are required.

#### `/=`

This bit is weird. Why do we do divide and assign, instead of just dividing? Technically, `n/~n&1` will be parsed as `x=n/~n` then `x&1`. This is not the behavior we want: `n/~n` is always equal to `0`. What we want is to have `n/(~n&1)`. It could work well, but the whole answer would be `n->n/(~n&1)`. The `/=` operator is a shortcut to that as it evaluates the right-hand side entirely, so we can get rid of parenthesis, gaining one byte. Assigning is a side effect we can live with.

Answer (score 13):

## MATLAB/Octave, <s>17</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)*

```matlab
@(x)x(i^2^x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCs0IjM84orkLzf5ptYl6xNRdXSmZxgYa6Z15BaYmVkbomlO9fWgISAPLTNIw00VSZYVdmhqbOEChcUlQJlDKEqXctKsovUsjLL1EoySjKL88DqkhOLEnOUHCFKHDVy00tLk5MT9XkSs1LQTPOHGGeOXkG/gcA)
Anonymous function. Throws indexing error for odd numbers.

This function returns element from input at index `i^2^x = (-1)^x`, so

- at index `1` for even numbers (which is input itself)
- at index `-1` for odd numbers (which is invalid index since indices in MATLAB start at 1)

Answer (score 11):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 10 bytes

I think this uses an approach that isn't yet represented in the other answers.

*–1 byte thanks to att!*

```
#+0^I^#^2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1nbIM4zTjnOSO2/S360QkBRZl5JtJJnXkFpia2SjkK2jgKQzC8tgfDTo7NjY3UUqoHChjoKJrUKsf//AwA) Here `I` represents the imaginary number *i*. Since the square of every even number is a multiple of 4, `I^#^2` equals 1 when the input is even, and so `0^I^#^2` becomes \$0^1\$ which is a perfectly nice 0 to add to the input. However, since the square of every odd number is one more than a multiple of 4, `I^#^2` equals *i* when the input is odd, and so `0^I^#^2` becomes \$0^i\$ which throws an "Indeterminate expression " error.

### first submission: 11 bytes

```
#+0^(-1)^#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1nbIE5D11AzTlntv0t@tEJAUWZeSbSSZ15BaYmtko5Cto4CkMwvLYHw06OzY2N1FKqBwoY6Cia1CrH//wMA) Since –1 to an even power equals 1, `0^(-1)^#` becomes \$0^1\$ when the input is even, which is a perfectly nice 0 to add to the input; however, since –1 to an odd power equals –1, `0^(-1)^#` becomes \$0^{-1}\$ (the reciprocal of 0) when the input is odd, which throws an error.

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1nbIM4zTjnOSO2/S360QkBRZl5JtJJnXkFpia2SjkK2jgKQzC8tgfDTo7NjY3UUqoHChjoKJrUKsf//AwA)

Comment: So clever! Thank you

Answer (score 10):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
₂ḭ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%82%E1%B8%AD&inputs=42&header=&footer=)

-1 thanks to Aaron Miller

```
₂  # Is_even(n) (Vyxal has no booleans, only 0 and 1)
 ḭ # Integer division (ordinary division doesn't error on 0)
```

Comment: [2 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%82%E1%B8%AD&inputs=42&header=&footer=)

Comment: YOO 2 BYTES WHAT THE HELL

Comment: @LeopardLGD It's because Vyxal has no booleans, only 0 and 1.

Comment: I see the explanation, I am just very glad and surprised for someone to finally break the 3 bytes barrier

Comment: @LeopardLGD Vyxal's cool like that.

Comment: Doesn't this not count b/c it still prints to console? So you have to supress it using -O and appending a ,?

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 20 bytes

```r
n=scan();n+(n%%2&&a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTOk9bI09V1UhNLVHzv8l/AA)

The `&&` operator is logical AND, evaluating left to right until the result is determined. If `n` is even then `n%%2` is `0`, coerced to `FALSE`, and the `a` part of the expression is therefore not evaluated. We then output `n+0`, ie `n`.

If `n` is odd, then `n%%2` is 1, coerced to `TRUE`, and we need to evaluate the `a` part of the expression to determine the result of `n%%2&&a`. Since `a` is undefined, this produces an error.

This strategy comes out 3 bytes shorter than [Dominic's strategy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229061/86301) with `if`.

Comment: `(n=scan())+(n%%2&&a)` same length

Comment: `n=scan();n[!n%%2||a]` same length

Answer (score 8):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>31</s> <s>25</s> <s>14</s> 19 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to @mazzy*

```powershell
param($n)$n/!($n%2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPUyVPXxFIqxpp/v//3xAA)

Calculates the modulo of the input number and `2`, implicitly converts the result to a boolean in order to negate it, then divides the input number by the negation. Inadvertently ditched the spec for a while there, sorry!

Comment: @mazzy Beautiful, can't believe I missed this.

Comment: [-1 byte more](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPUyVPXxFIqxpp/v//3wwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: I'm sorry. The code `1/...` does not `output that number`. It should be `"$args"/...` or `param($n)$n/...`

Comment: Doesn't currently conform to spec since even numbers aren't printed.

Comment: @valisstillwithMonica fixed.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 17 bytes

```python
lambda n:n/(~n%2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk9foy5P1Ujzf0FRZl6JRpqGkaYmF4xtrKn5HwA)

thanks to @hyper-neutrino for -4 bytes

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:n%2and 1/0 or n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk/VKDEvRcFQ30Ahv0gh739BUWZeiUaahpGmJheMbayp@R8A)

Comment: i think ~-n%2 works

Comment: Stealing from user for the second program, you can use `g` instead of `1/0` to get a NameError (or any other undefined variable)

Comment: 16 bytes: `lambda n:n>>n%-2`

Comment: Improvement for your 24 bytes: remove space between 0 and `or`

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Throws <s>a `TypeError`</s> an overflow error on odd numbers. ***Still** convinced* there must be a much shorter way  `/v` would work if JavaScript errored on division by 0.

```
*v ªß
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=KnYgqt8&input=OA)

```
*v ªß     :Implicit input of integer
*         :Multiply by
 v        :  Divisible by 2?
   ª      :Logical OR with
    ß     :A recursive call
```

Comment: Wow, that's indeed short

Comment: @LeopardLGD, give it a minute and one of the other golfing languages will be along to kick my ass!

Comment: Your prediction was indeed correct :)

Comment: Oh no. RIP to this!

Comment: Not _even_ a minute, @hyper-neutrino 

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 15 bytes

```
[ 2 / 1 shift ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JgzcVlpGD8P1rBSEFfwVChOCMzrUQhFsjXU4hVSM7PLcgvTlVIynT4DwA)

*Thanks to @umnikos*

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 19 bytes

```
[ dup 1 + 2 mod / ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JgzcVlpGD8P1ohpbRAwVBBW8FIITc/RUFfIRYopqcQq5Ccn1uQX5yqkJTp8B8A)

Throws a divide by zero error on odd numbers, while returning even numbers.

### Explanation:

- `dup` Duplicate the input.

  **Stack:** (e.g.) `2 2`
- `1 +` Add one.

  **Stack:** `2 3`
- `2 mod` Modulo two.

  **Stack:** `2 1`
- `/` Divide. (Here is where the error happens for odd input.)

  **Stack:** `2`

Here's a slightly longer version that simply asserts the number is not odd:

```
[ dup odd? f assert= ]
```

Comment: 15 bytes: `[ 2 / 1 shift ]`

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 10 bytes

```javascript
n=>n%2?_:n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5P1cg@3irvf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGiaYmF6qIqabmfwA)

Not a very hard answer

Comment: I was hoping something like `n=>[n][n%2]` would work and be shorter, but I can't get TIO working right now, and it's not even shorter!

Comment: @Pureferret that wouldn't error on odd numbers as it would simply return undefined.

Comment: Hmm, yup makes sense. If I could have run TIO I would have seen that :D

Comment: Ah, beat me to it

Comment: @Yelp anyone with js knowledge could write this. I just happened to answer first, and thanks to FGITW, I have 4 upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

## MMIX, 12 bytes (3 instrs)

```
ihateodds   PBEV  $0,0F     // if(n even) goto ret;
            LDVTS $0,$0,6   // privileged instruction
0H          POP   1,0       // ret: return n
```

The `LDVTS` tries to make whatever memory page the input points to RWX in the cache, though not in the page table (if the input is one more than a multiple of 8). This is a privileged instruction for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 7):

## [PHP](https://php.net), 14.

```
die($argv[0]);
```

There's no need to differentiate odd and even. The criteria say odd numbers can display *any* error, while even ones should be displayed.

Since the criteria allow for ANY error on an even number, and die() displays an error and terminates, the input is fine as an error.

The criteria allow for even numbers to be displayed in any manner, including as an error, so again, the input is fine as an error.

But if die() isn't accepted as an error, and a genuine terminating error's required...  **<s>27</s> 26 bytes**. Sadly we can't use `die()` here...

```
echo($a=$argv[1])%2?$b:$a;
```

If warnings are acceptable as errors, then in the comments [Matthew Anderson](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94492/matthew-anderson)'s suggestion to use division by zero also gives us **26 bytes**:

```
echo($a=$argv[1])/!($a%2);
```

Comment: This was mine:

`$i/=1-$i%2;`

Comment: @MatthewAnderson Ooh, clever trick, I like it! Can't see a way to make that super short with $argv[0]. but it feels like there *has* to be one.

Comment: `1/!($argv[1]%2);` There you go

Comment: @MatthewAnderson Testing with `php -r 'echo 1/!($argv[1]%2);' 2` that brings it down to 21 bytes, but unfortunately it only outputs `1` for even numbers, rather than the number itself. But we can get it down to 25 with: `die($a=$argv[1])/!($a%2);` Division by zero is only a warning rather than an error, but that could be moot since we're using die() anyway.

Comment: No, I'm wrong, we need to use echo, or the die() terminates it too early, so, I can't do better than 26 bytes whichever approach we take.

Comment: `${$argv[1&$argv[1]+1]/1};` 25 bytes, no echos

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 17 bytes

```python
lambda x:[x][x%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fYZuZV6KRmVdQWqKhqcmVZqvxPycxNyklUaHCKroiNrpC1Sj2vyZXQRFIWZpGhabmfyMA)

It's very simple - construct a list with a single (zeroth) number and take an element of it with index equal to that number modulo 2. Since there is no element 1, it will obviously throw an exception on odd input.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>25</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes after looking at [ophact's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229060/95126), and then -1 byte thanks to Robin Ryder*

```r
`if`((n=scan())%%2,,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyEzLUFDI8@2ODkxT0NTU1XVSEcnT/O/8X8A)

Throws an 'argument is missing' error when `n` is odd and the `if` expression tries to read the missing expression that should be between the two commas.

Comment: [20 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229149/86301) using `&&` instead of `if`.

Comment: `n=scan();if(T[1+n%%2])n` is also 23 bytes with a different error; maybe it can be shortened.

Comment: @RobinRyder - Yes!  Thanks!  Although I'm still far from matching/beating you or qwr...

Comment: I think your current version fails for n=0, unfortunately.

Comment: Drat!  You're right... rolling back...

Comment: `"if"((n=scan())%%2,,n)` works for -1 byte: you can remove the `m`, and get an `Error: argument is missing, with no default`.

Comment: @RobinRyder - That's amazing: I didn't even think to try that, I was so *sure* it wouldn't work.  But it does: thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
#/Mod[#+1,2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1nfNz8lWlnbUMcoVu1/QFFmXolDerShQSwXjG0c@/8/AA)

-1 byte from @att

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1nfNz8lWlnbUMcoVu1/QFFmXolDerShQSwXjG0c@/8/AA)

Comment: `#+0^(-1)^#&` works for 11 bytes (and also is a new mechanism among the answers, as far as I can tell)

Comment: @GregMartin very nice! I think that you should post this as your own answer... I want to upvote it!

Comment: Cool, [answer posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229147/56178) :)

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>28</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

-13 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)
-1 thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%c3%a9goire)

```c
f(a){a/=~a&1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1GzOlHfti5RzdC69n9mXolCbmJmnoYmVzWXAhAUFAGF0jSUVFOUdNI0TDQ1rbEIm4KEa///S07LSUwv/q9bDgA)

How `~a&1` works is explained in [this solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229111/16236).

Comment: No need to print it seems (modifying function arguments is acceptable), so save 13 bytes  [TIO](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1GzOlHfVrcuUdXIuvZ/Zl6JQm5iZp6GJlc1lwIQFBQBhdI0lFRTlHTSNEw0Na2xCJuChGv//0tOy0lML/6vWw4A)

Comment: Why don't you need to return `a`? The result of the division is in `eax` which is also used for return value, but isn't there undefined behaviour in this code?

Comment: @OskarSkog Undefined behavior is the way of life when golfing C.

Comment: `f(a){a/=~a&1;}` saves a byte. See [my (lengthy) explanations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229111/16236)

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 13 bytes

```
+`[13579]$
99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fOyHa0NjU3DJWhcvS8v9/IwA) Explanation: If the number is odd, simply keeps appending `9`s until Retina eventually runs out of memory, or until TIO kills it, whichever is sooner.

If you want a more direct error, then for 21 bytes:

```
[13579]$
9999999999$*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/2tDY1NwyVoXLEg5UtP7/twQA) Explanation: Tries to append more than a 32-bit integer length of `9`s to the odd input, which throws an OverflowException.

Answer (score 6):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>11</strike> 10 bytes

```
1/($1%2-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fUF9DxVDVSNdQE8g2AQA)

*Thanks to tail spark rabbit ear for helping drop one char...*

Divides by zero if the number is odd, otherwise the test is truthy and the default action prints the commandline..

Comment: Worked without heading +, even 0 is given.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't get that (meaning `0` printing w/o the `+`) from the commandline, but it does work on TIO for some reason..  I'll update the code and add a caveat in the description, thanks!

Comment: are you a non-GNU AWK user or a non-POSIX AWK user?

Comment: GNU AWK here...  Everything I have access to is Linux or MacOS these days.

Comment: How about `-f path/to/your/script`?

Comment: Well, I can't find a system that DOES need the leading `+` so my best guess is that an earlier version of the code needed it?  But I took your suggestion and dropped it from the answer.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function

```apl
⊢÷1-2|⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXosPbDXWNaoCM/2mP2iY86u171NX8qHfNo94th9YbP2qb@KhvanCQM5AM8fAM/p@mYMSVpmACxMYA)

`⊢` the argument

`÷` divided by

`1-` one minus

`2|` the division remainder when 2 divides

`⊢` the argument

Or in other words:$$x\over{1-\Big({x\over2}-\big\lfloor{x\over2}\big\rfloor}\Big)$$

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 9 bytes

```perl
$_%2&&die
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXtVITS0lM/X/f@N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Comment: `$[=$_%2` for 7

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
Èи¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cMeFHYf2//9vBAA)

or

```
È×F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cMfh6W7//xsBAA)

`È` checks if the input is even. Returns `1` for even numbers, `0` for odd numbers.

- `и` creates a list of this many copies of the input, and `¿` calculates the gcd of the list [and throws an error for empty lists](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/issues/178)
- `×` repeats the input as a string this many times. This results in the input for even inputs and the empty string for odd inputs. `F` is a for loop which crashes if it gets the empty string as an argument. In the end the stack is empty and the input is implicitly printed. `F` could be any of `E`, `F`, `G` and `ƒ`.

Comment: That moment when you create a list and basically implement an if-else statement in 3 god damn bytes

Answer (score 5):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) (math function), 14 bytes

```sh
((1/1&~$1,$1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxDoAgDAXQnVP8gZg2UbTewxu4ERpcIBFcNHp11Pm9s8SmR/J1y6lgWKAQiFHitRHJKN1jpbfC3DTvqKFU0CXOzdPNBgg@ZlgiKP3G@OIL)

Unlike in Bash, C and many other languages, in Zsh `&` binds more tightly than `/` by default, allowing us to get division by zero on odd numbers with just `1 / 1 & ~$1`.

(Zsh does have a `C_PRECEDENCES` option which changes arithmetic binding to the traditional order.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ḂNXo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjia/iPz///@bAQA)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
%2NXo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/VyC8i/////6YA)

Look ma, no unicode!

```
ḂNXo  Main Link
Ḃ     Same thing as %2. 1 if it's odd, 0 if it's even.
 N    Negate. -1 if it's odd, 0 if it's even.
  X   Random number. Errors with -1 as input, returns 0 with 0 as input.
   o  Logical OR. If the input was odd, the program's already errored. Otherwise, it's 0,
      so logical OR gives the right value, which is the input.
```

Unfortunately, since dividing by zero isn't actually an error in Jelly, I cannot use that. Although, it wouldn't save me any bytes: `%2C:@` is the same length.

Comment: Damn this is fascinating, how the hell does this even work

Comment: @LeopardLGD Added a full explanation

Comment: I am just very surprised how these golfing languages already have prebuilt tools for basically anything.

Comment: @LeopardLGD, that's the whole point of golfing languages!

Comment: Yeah, but how the hell do they have E V E R Y T H I N G? For every question, no matter the complexity, there's that one guy with 05AB1E or Jelly, that already answered the question with a single-digit amount of bytes.

Comment: @LeopardLGD because most challenges aren't actually extremely complex, lol

Comment: @LeopardLGD, that speaks either to the triviality of the challenge or the quality of the golfer or both.

Answer (score 4):

## [A0A0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A0A0), <strike>161</strike> <strike>146</strike> 138 bytes

```
I0A10A6V0
G-1G-1A5G0D2A0
A8O0
G1
A0A0
A0C3G1G1A0
A0L1S2M4
A0A1G-3G-3A0
G-3


G-1G-1



A0A0
C3G1G1A0C3G1G1A0
G-10A0G-10A0
A0A1G-3G-3A0
G-3
```

Since A0A0 does not have a modulo, or division, this uses repeated subtraction by 2 to get down to either a 0 or 1. If 1, the number is odd, if 0 the number is even.

```
I0  A10 A6 V0
G-1 G-1 A5 G0 D2 A0
A8  O0
```

Reads a number from the input `I0` and distributes the operand over two other lines. `A5 G0 D2 A0` completes the loop below in which we inserted the operand and `A8 O0` finishes the print function.

```
A0  A0
A0  C3 G1  G1  A0
A0  L1 S2  M4  V0 G0 D2 A0
A0  A1 G-3 G-3 A0
G-3
```

With the inserted code executed before this completes a loop that compares the operand to 1 and jumps to 1 (operand is greater than 1), 0 (operand is equal to 1) or -1 (operand is less than one) lines down depending on the comparison. We add 2 to this and multiple it by 4, to get the offsets 12, 8 and 4.

```
A0   A0
C3   G1 G1   A0  C3 G1 G1 A0
G-10 A0 G-10 A0
A0   A1 G-3  G-3 A0
G-3
```

This is a loop located 12 lines down, executed when the operand is 2 or more, to jump back up to the repeated subtraction loop. It's padded with no-ops `G1`, since the loop must have three instructions or more to work.

At offset 8 is nothing, to stop the program.

At offset 4 is the code `A6 V0 O0`. The `A6` is a leftover from copying, but the last two print the initial value that was entered.

Edit: forgot to mention, but A0A0 has no errors or exceptions, so this only halts.

Edit 2: Optimized by 15 bytes. I misunderstood the default loop template I make use of in the code. I was under the impression that the amount of G1 and G-3 instructions on line 2 and 4 of the loop resp. needed to match the amount of instructions inside the loop. This is not the case, you only need two of them (although more also work, as long as each line has an equal amount of them). This change removes these extra instructions.

Edit 3: Optimized by 8 bytes. Because of edit two, it turns out that there's actually no minimum of three instructions in the loop. This allows us to drop four instructions (not two, since the loop at the bottom is partially evaluated), totalling eight bytes. I've also added a link to the language page in the post, since that was not present.

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
(x=scan())[[!x%%2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X6PCtjg5MU9DUzM6WrFCVdUoNva/Mdd/AA)

## R 4.1, <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
\(x)x[[!x%%2]]
```

Takes advantage of the fact that an R numeric is automatically a vector.

-1 byte by using a different indexing error due to Dominic van Essen.

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/XyPPtjg5MU9DUzM6WjFPVdUoNva/8X8A)...

Comment: (and 14 bytes for the R 4.1 version using the same strategy: ```\(x)x[[!x%%2]]```)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen thanks, updated

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 7 bytes

```
:2%?Cn;
```

The input should be put onto the stack using the `-v` command-line argument.

[Try it even!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38pI1d45z/r///@6ZQpGAA)
[Try it odd!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38pI1d45z/r///@6ZQqGAA)

---

#### Explanation:

Initially, the stack contains the input number, \$ n \$.

- `:` duplicates the top of stack: [\$n\$, \$n\$]
- `2` pushes \$2\$ onto stack: [\$n\$, \$n\$, \$2\$]
- `%` pops two values and pushes their modulo: [\$n\$, \$n \% 2\$]
- `?` pops the top value, and if it is \$0\$, the next instruction is skipped: [\$n\$]

If \$n \% 2 \neq 0\$:

- `C` is not a valid instruction, so the program crashes.

If \$n \% 2 = 0\$:

- `n` pops off the top value (\$n\$) and prints it: []
- `;` terminates the program.

Comment: You don't need the `;`

Comment: @JoKing Do I not? The question author specified "As for even numbers, no errors must occur and the output is the number." in a comment on the question.

Comment: Ah, that part wasn't in the actual question so I missed it

Answer (score 4):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 44 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
S _Duplicate_input][S S S T S N
_Push_2][T  S T T   _Modulo][N
T   S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_EVEN][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_nonexistent_Label][N
S S N
_Create_Label_Even][T   N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters S (space), T (tab), and N (new-line) added as highlighting only.
[..._some_action] added as explanation only.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDIAgIgxanACRRS4ALJAQmgAFDN///mAA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer input = STDIN as integer
Integer temp = input modulo-2
If (temp == 0):
  Go to label EVEN
Go to nonexistent label (causing an error)

Label EVEN:
  Print input as integer
  (also shows an error: no exit defined; could be prevented by adding three trailing newlines)
```

Answer (score 4):

### [<>^v](https://github.com/Astroide/---v), 10 bytes

```
2,tT%1=VT;
```

###### Explanation

```
2,tT%1=VT;

2          Push 2 to the stack
 ,         Read number from stdin
  t        Pop stack and store into variable `t` 
   T       Push the value of the variable `t` on the stack
    %      Modulo top of the stack by second element of stack
     1     Push 1
      =    Execute next instruction only if top 2 elements of the stack are equal
       V   Access variable V, which is undefined and cannot be set because its setter is a keyword (throws error)
        T  Push value of variable `t` onto stack
         ; Print top of stack
```

It tests if the number entered modulo 2 returns 1, if so (odd) it tries to access an undefined variable, so that throws an error and exits. If the modulo result is 0 (even), it pushes the number (stored in a variable), and then prints the top of the stack.

[online link](https://v.astroide.repl.co/#a95d1914c22c30f413eb1c56b4a2d033e4a4c22d6cad2935cd49939373c93521) (the `>` is the input prompt, it is not an output of the program)

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 12 bytes

```hs
f x|even x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hoia1LDVPocK24n9uYmaegq1CSj6XgkJBUWZeiYKKQpqCCQrPDIVn/h8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
./₂ℕ∨ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X0//UVPTo5apjzpWaD1qavz/39DQ9H8UAA)

#### Explanation

Raising up an error in Brachylog is surprisingly difficult (outside of transpilation errors obviously): in general in declarative logic programming it is better for predicates to fail ("return" false) rather than to throw errors (which has side-effects). Many things that you would expect to error don’t error, they simply don’t succeed to allow backtracking.

The simplest way to raise an error I thought about is to force computation (i.e. use floating point arithmetic, not constraint integer arithmetic) of something undefined: computing `ln(0)`.

@UnrelatedString found a 1 byte way to error: trying to cast a string to an integer, when the input string is a free variable.

```
.             Input = Output
 /₂           Divide it by 2
   ℕ          It must result in a non-negative integer
     ∨        If all that fails
      ị       Try to cast a free variable from string to int
```

Comment: Took longer than I hoped to actually find it, but [`ị` also doesn't seem to like free variables](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X0//UVPTo5apjzpWPNzd/f@/oaHp/ygA)

Comment: @UnrelatedString I didn’t even remember this predicate existed :/

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>31</strike> <strike>23</strike> 22 bytes

```python
lambda x:x&1and a or x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkLNMDEvRSFRIb9IoeJ/QVFmXolGmoaZpiYXjG2BxDbV1PwPAA)

Very simple answer, if the number is odd it just tries to check the value of an undefined variable.

*-8 bytes!* thanks to @Wasif

*-1 byte* due to replacing if .. else with and..or

Comment: [23 bytes! (You can mash `2` and `else` together plus the `print` can be removed, you just need to return, and the `print` can be done in the footer section)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKlEhM02hQtUoNac4VaHif0FRZl6JRpqGmaYmF4xtgcQ21dT8DwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 5 bytes

```
|b%[0
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7Cb%25%5B0&inputs=4)

Explanation:

```
|       take input
 b      add to print buffer
  %     modulo (mod 2 by default)
   [0   the first half of an if statement checking whether the answer is 0
```

Why this works: If the input is even, the result of `%` is 0 so the if statement is used. The if statement is empty however so nothing happens (and the print buffer is printed implicitly). If the input is odd, the result of `%` is not 0, so the interpreter will keep skipping forward looking for a closing `]` which is not to be found (the language will try to close the bracket from the if statement if it's not allowed to enter the if statement), resulting in an error.

## Old best:

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 7 bytes

```python
|b%[1{]
```

[Try it online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7Cb%25%5B1%7B%5D&inputs=5)

## Explanation

```python
|            takes the user's input
 b           adds this input to a print buffer
  %          checks to see if this value is odd (mod 2 is default)
   [1 ]      if the resulting value is 1, the code in this if statement executes
     {       this is an unsupported character, so it throws an exception
             buffer gets printed implicitly if an error was not thrown
```

## Note

Technically, this code could be reduced to 6 bytes by removing the `]` from the end.

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](//golang.org), 79 bytes

```go
package main
import."fmt"
func main(){a:=[]int{0}
Scan(&a[0])
print(a[a[0]%2])}
```

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, <sup><s>9</s></sup> 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/98541)

```
sum(dim(identity(Ans/2
```

Tries to create a `Ans/2`-size identity matrix, which will fail for odd numbers

It will also fails for big-ish numbers depending on the available RAM

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 12 bytes

```scala
i=>i/(i+1&1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc3BCsIgHAfg@57ixxihjK15jSZ07NCtF7ClYMhfUYtCfHYjOn3HL23KqeZvD71lXJQl6HfWdE84hYDSvZSDOeBMGav80@wq7Z7ZUewEb8ZHMMJxwoLsIRaOEC1lRyz1A2GSGEr6LfMzWzdf46cYRrzWnne1fQE)

Answer (score 2):

## [GNU-APL](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/), 9 bytes

```
{⍵÷2⊤⍵+1}
```

The above function divdes the given number n with (n+1) mod 2.

Samples for 2 and 3

```
      {⍵÷2⊤⍵+1} 2
2
      {⍵÷2⊤⍵+1} 3
DOMAIN ERROR
λ1[1]  λ←⍵÷2⊤⍵+1
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##SyzI0c1Lz/v//1Hf1EdtE6of9W49vN3oUdcSIEPbsFbBiAuHhPH//wA) in ngn/apl.

Answer (score 2):

## **[BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/)**, <strike>7</strike> 6 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
¯2⥊⍟|⊢
```

[Try it here.](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgwq8y4qWK4o2ffOKKogoKRiAyCkYgMw==)

How it works:

```
¯2⥊⍟|⊢
  ⥊     # reshape (this can be any function that is not dyadically invertible)
   ⍟    # power modifier (⍟ applies ,  number of times)
¯2  |⊢  # input mod ¯2, gives 0 if even, ¯1 if odd.
```

`⍟0` is just equivalent to the identity function so it returns the input, and `⍟¯1` calls the inverse of  1 time, but since `⥊` can't be inverted it gives an error.

---

### 7 Byte solution:

```
⊢⊣·!2|¬
```

[Try it here.](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oqi4oqjwrchMnzCrAoKRiAyCkYgMw==)

How it works:

```
⊢⊣·!2|¬
      ¬  # not (in BQN not(x) is extended to 1-x)
    2|   # mod 2
  ·!     # assert (throws an error if not 1)
⊢⊣       # return the input
```

Comment: Nice! Gonna add you to the leaderboard a little bit later

Comment: +1, and you can get to 5 bytes by dropping the minus sign and using a function that errors when given two integers, [for example `∊`](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgMuKIiuKNn3ziiqIKCkYgMgpGIDM=).

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```lisp
(λ(x)(/ x(modulo(add1 x)2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE5nBppKSmZealKqT91zi3W6NCU0NfoUIjNz@lNCdfIzElxVChQtNIU1PzvyYXl0aagqHmfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 14 bytes

```cs
a=>a%2<1?a:a/0

a=>                 # Function taking a
   a%2<1            # Boolean which is true if a is even 
        ?a          # If true return a
          :a/0      # If false return a/0 which errors
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXoqMAJOwU0oBcBdv/ibZ2iapGNob2iVaJ@gb/rbnCizJLUjVAshpGmpoofGMg/z8A)

Comment: Why the downvote, is there something I can change?

Comment: Probably downvoted because it fails for negative odd numbers. (I didn't downvote.) Try your code with `-3` as input, for instance.

Comment: The challenge does say non-negative integer though, so maybe something else

Comment: Oh, my bad, you're entirely correct!

Answer (score 2):

## [Starry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry), 18 bytes

```
, +       +    *'.
```

```
0,    push input
1+    duplicate
7+    push 2
4*    modulo
0'    jump to label 0 if top is non-zero
0.    print top
```

If the input mod 2 is non-zero (1) it attempts to jump to a label that doesn't exist, so it throws an error. Otherwise it reaches the end and prints the number.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLCqq/P9fR0FbAQLAtJa63v//AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore BASIC (C64/THEC64, PET, C128, VIC-20, C16/+4) - <strike>18 14 BASIC bytes used</strike> <- invalid entries (now removed) - <strike>25</strike> <strike>19</strike> 17 BASIC bytes

```
0INPUTN:ONNAND1GOTO1:PRINTN
```

It takes any numeric input and logically ANDs it with 1; Therefore for every odd number, this is `1` otherwise it is `0`. This value is passed to the `ON...GOTO` command. Where this is zero, it passes through to `PRINT N` and the program exits gracefully. Where this value is one, it will branch to line `1` which is not there, and therefore it reports an `?UNDEF'D STATEMENT  ERROR IN 0`.

The old entry did not output any valid number, and so was removed. It was something like this:

```
0INPUTN:N=NAND1:IFNTHENX
```

Comment: Does this actually output N (as required by the challenge) when N is even?  It looks as if it'll just end without outputting anything...

Comment: Ah I must have been not awake enough when initially making the programs. It is easy to fix

Comment: Delete line 1 to save 3 (?) bytes

Comment: How would I get the error in that instance? Or maybe I would. Let's try. But I think the line number is two bytes, the x is 1, then there's two bytes that point at the next line, and each line ends with two or three more bytes in Commodore BASIC

Comment: Because GOTO line 1 will throw an 'UNDEF'D STATEMENT ERROR IN 0' error (since line 1 doesn't exist).  Tested on https://virtualconsoles.com/online-emulators/c64/

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 14 bytes

```
=A1/ISEVEN(A1)
```

Input is in the cell `A1`. The formula can go anywhere else.

`ISEVEN()` is a built-in that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. When you perform a math operation (like dividing), Excel treats `TRUE` as `1` and `FALSE` as `0`. So odd numbers will try to divide by zero and return an error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 21 bytes

```python
lambda x:x//((x+1)%2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRocKqQl9fQ6NC21BT1Ujzf0FRZl6JRpqGkaYmF4xtrKn5HwA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) page for ways you can golf your program. I've edited your post slightly to improve the formatting

Comment: thanks a lot, caird! i would actually have preferred to just comment a slightly longer python solution above but i don't have the reputation needed to do so.

Comment: We generally recommend against posting solutions in comments, as answers don't have the be the shortest they can be, so long as they make an effort at golfing :)

Comment: ok, understood!

Answer (score 2):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 12 bytes

```
/??/!!//?/?/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X9/eXl9RUV/fHgj/2wPBfwA)

The `///` language is Turing complete, yet only has one command: a simple `/find/replace/`. No special characters except the forward and back slashes. Each `/find/replace/` loops until it can no more, before moving onto the next. In `///`, the input is appended to the end of the program. The link places the input in the footer.

This program uses unary to represent numbers, taking input with `?` and returning output with `!`.

```
/??/!!/    Replaces all pairs of '?', with pairs of '!'
/?/?/      Replaces any '?' left with itself, creating an infinite loop
```

On evens, all questions are replaced with exclamations in the first pattern, and the program terminates with as many exclamations as it had questions. The same number is returned in unary.

On odds, after the first pattern there is one question mark left. This gets replaced with itself ad infinitum until TIO times out after 60 seconds.

There's technically no consensus that this counts as an error, but I'm counting TIO as the implementation here. Otherwise, I can certainly write another implementation that times out, or that uses recursion to eventually [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 2):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 103 bytes

```python
N
Count i while _%60/48 {
_*60+N
Count j while 10/(_%60)*(i-j+1) {
Write _/60^(i-j+1)%60/(1-_/60%2)
}
}
```

Dies with a division-by-zero error if the input is odd. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhXtXMQN/EQqGaK17LzEAbJp0FlTY00NcAKdHU0sjUzdI21AQqDC/KLAFq1DcziIMKgszQMNQFCakaaXLVctX@/29kbAoA)

#### Explanation

We start with a loop that reads digits into the accumulator until hitting a newline:

```python
N
Count i while _%60/48 {
_*60+N
}
```

At the end of this loop, the accumulator can be read as a base-60 number whose digits are the entered characters' ASCII codes (the last one being 10 for newline). The loop variable `i` is one less than the number of digits in the input number. We need to know the length of the number to output the digits in order; since `i` goes out of scope as soon as its loop exits, we'll need to nest the output loop inside the input loop.

Naively, we could output the digits like so:

```python
Count j while i-j+1 {
Write _/60^(i-j+1)%60
}
```

But we only want this loop to activate when we've just read a newline; so we multiply the condition by `10/(_%60)`, which is `1` when the last character read has a code of 10 (or below) and `0` when it has a code above 10:

```python
Count j while 10/(_%60)*(i-j+1) {
```

Finally, we need an error when the input number is odd. This is the case if the final digit's character code (`_/60%60`) is odd; `1-_/60%2` will give `0` for odd and `1` for even. Then we can simply divide the output expression by this quantity to get the desired error/no-op behaviors:

```python
Write _/60^(i-j+1)%60/(1-_/60%2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [KonamiCode](http://esolangs.org/wiki/KonamiCode), 132 bytes

`>>>>(^^)v(>)>(^)v(>)L(>)>(^)v((>))>(^^)S(^)A(^^)v(^)A(^>^)L(^^)v(>)B(^^^)L(^^^)L(^>^)>(>)S((^))>(^)B(>)>(^^)S(>)A(^>)>(^>)<<L(^>)<<<`

This is basically identical to [my answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113448/is-this-even-or-odd/238032#238032), but with a bit of code on the end that causes an InvalidMemoryIndexError if the number is odd.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 9 bytes

```perl
$_%2&&die
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXtVITS0lM/X/fxMu03/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots),<s>41</s> 35 bytes

```
.&#$--\
*#1-*[-]/2#*.
\#?{+}*{%}[/]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxOzsxMyS8p/v9fT01ZRVc3hktL2VBXK1o3Vt9IWVdLjytG2b5au1arWrVWN1o/9v9/QyNjEwtTSwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 15 Bytes

```
print([n][n%2])
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first answer! Unfortunately, taking input from a predefined variable (here `n`) is not [one of our allowed I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447). You'll have to change your submission to a full program or a function like `lambda n:[n][n%2]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>30</s> <s>29</s> <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```
f(n)=[1...mod(n,2)8!][1]n
```

A lot of stuff that I tried just gives `undefined` instead of erroring out, but I finally found something that worked.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q259koxsor)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n1bhmqd4yw)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 57 bytes

```
main(c,v)char**v;{c=atoi(1[v]);printf("%d",(c%2)?0/0:c);}
```

Exploits the ternary conditional to divide by zero (fastest way of causing an error?) if the first argument isn't even. Also abuses the argc variable to store the number.

*Note: To compile using LLVM Clang, use flag `-std=c89`. However, Clang-compiled versions won't just go though with attempting to divide by zero. Sad.*

A longer one (works with gcc and clang):

```
main(c,v)char**v;{c=atoi(1[v]);printf("%d",(c%2)?v[9999]:c);}
```

Attempts to access memory outside the program's bounds when given an odd number. Try removing some 9s at the cost of making the likelihood of accessing memory outside the program's bounds smaller. Works with three 9s in TIO.

Yes, I know that `atoi` isn't exactly good, but it's nice and short.

Answer (score 2):

## Minecraft Command Blocks, 288 bytes

[image: command block picture]
The commands in command blocks from left to right:

```
scoreboard objectives add n dummy
scoreboard players set n n <Input>
scoreboard players operation s n = n n
scoreboard players set 2 n 2
scoreboard players operation n n %= 2 n
execute if score n n matches 0 run tellraw @a {"score":{"name":"s","objective":"n"}}
execute if score n n matches 1 run setblock ~ ~ ~1 redstone_block
e
```

I didn't count the second command block which sets the input. If it's counted the total is **315** bytes plus the length of the number.

### Explanation

`scoreboard objectives add n dummy` creates a scoreboard objective named n. Scoreboard objectives are a way to store numbers similar to variables. Each objective can have an infinite number of variables associated with it, which are accessed like `<name> <objective>`. So `s n` would refer to the variable named `s` in the objective `n`. All the variables in this program are in the objective n.

`scoreboard players set n n <Input>` sets n to the input.

`scoreboard players operation s n = n n` copies the value of n to s. This is required because scoreboard operations overwrite the original value.

`scoreboard players set 2 n 2` sets the value of the variable 2 to 2. This is required because scoreboard operations can only be done with two variables, not a variable and a number.

`scoreboard players operation n n %= 2 n` modulos n by 2.

`execute if score n n matches 0 run tellraw @a {"score":{"name":"s","objective":"n"}}` prints the value of s (which was set to n) if n is 0, which indicates the number was even.

`execute if score n n matches 1 run setblock ~ ~ ~1 redstone_block` sets the block to the right of the command block to a redstone block if n is 1, indicating the number is odd. This triggers the last command block.

`e` is an invalid command, which throws an error, as seen here.
[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 62 bytes

```
i=int(input())
if i%2==0:
    print(i)
else:
    raise Exception('')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTKzNNIVPVyNbWwIqLs6AILKXJlZpTnArkFyVmFqcquFYkpxaUZObnaaira/7/bwQA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes thanks to [@hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)

```
i=int(input())
if i%2<1:print(i)
else:1/0
```

[Try it online 2!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTKzNNIVPVyMbQqqAILK7JlZpTnGplqG/w/78RAA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes thanks to [@user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)

```
i=int(input())
if i%2:g
else:print(i)
```

[Try it online 3!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTKzNNIVPVyCqdKzWnONWqoAgsqfn/vyEA)

Comment: Why not golf it more? You can remove the `==0` part by swapping the two branches

Comment: You can remove some spaces (by inlining your if/else) for a trivial golf. Also, `i%2==0` is the same as `i%2<1`. Also, you can `raise 0` which isn't valid but... you're trying to produce an error anyway :) you can also just divide by zero to get an error; that should be the shortest way to obtain any error

Comment: That's true, gonna add it. And to @user, I am not interested much in making these, I am more interested in making the task itself, not the answer. I am doing this just for fun so even if I golf the answer, it won't be a competitive one.

Comment: [Here's](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTKzNNIVPVyCqdKzWnONWqoAgsqfn/vzEA) a slightly golfed version that doesn't change your original too much.

Comment: @LeopardLGD It doesn't have to be a competitive one - you can just try your best instead of trying to win. It's up to you to decide what to do with your answers, though.

Comment: Btw you don't need the `<1` in the second one (or the `==0` in the first one). You can do `if i%2:1/0\nelse:print(i)` instead, or just an undefined variable such as `g` instead of `1/0` as I did above.

Comment: That's also true.

Comment: [23 as a function](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHTKl0hM00hU9UoNac4VSHzf0FRZl6JRpqGiaYmF4xtqqn5HwA)

Comment: @ophact Wasif already has a shorter one as a function

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
Ｉ§0#Ｎθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEw7HEMy8ltUJDyUBZSUfBM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDEwisuSBKCzWt//83@q9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｉ§0#Ｎ
```

Cyclically (i.e. modulo 2) index into the string `0#` using the input as an integer, and try to cast that character into an integer. This throws a ValueError for `#`.

```
θ
```

Print the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 6 bytes

```
VkX%aa
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's the 7-byte equivalent in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/LDsiUdUo8f///2YmAA)

#### Explanation

```
    a   Command-line argument
   %    Mod 2: 0 if even, 1 if odd
 kX     Repeat the string ", " that many times
V       Eval
        If even, eval empty string (no-op); if odd, eval ", " (parse error)
     a  If there wasn't an error, autoprint the command-line argument
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>74</s> 45 bytes

```c
main(i){scanf("%i",&i);printf("%i",i/=~i&1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS/@vnJmXnFOakqpgU1ySkpmvl2H3PzcxM08jU7O6ODkxL01DSTVTSUctU9O6oCgzrwTKz9S3rctUM9S0rv3/3xgA)

Takes an `int` for input, then uses an if-else statement to choose if the number is odd or even. If the number's odd, it doesn't output anything, but shows the error anyway. Even numbers display the error, but at least the number is inputted.

Thanks to ceilingcat, with the help of Olivier Grégoire, for golfing 29 bytes.

Comment: You can flip the if statement pretty easy, as well as remove the `printf` statement for the error. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///PzcxM08jU7O6ODkxL01DSTVTSUctU9M6M00jU9VIszpT39bAujY1pzi1uqAoM68EqgSoorb2/39jAA "C (clang) – Try It Online"). You can also combine the two sides of the if into one statment for 46 bytes

Comment: @JoKing How to combine? I'm a beginner, so I don't know how.

Comment: Dividing `i` by zero within the print statement if `i%2` is 1, otherwise dividing by 1.

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS/@vnJmXnFOakqpgU1ySkpmvl2H3PzcxM08jU7O6ODkxL01DSTVTSUctU9O6oCgzrwTKz9S3rctUM9S0rv3/3xgA), building upon @ceilingcat's suggestion

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS/@vnJmXnFOakqpgU1ySkpmvl2H3PzcxM08jU7O6ODkxL01DSTVTSUctU9O6oCgzryRNI1PVyN4KLAgUq/3/3xgA) by using a null pointer

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 16 bytes

```sh
<<<$1>0
<$[$1%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGxdDOgMtGJVrFUNUo9v///4ZGxgA)

Comment: Does the downvoter have any feedback to suggest?

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
n->n[~n&1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvs/T9cuL7ouT80w9n9BUWZeSU6eRpqGkaYmF4JngsIzA/KQuMaamv8B)

Numbers can be indexed by one (`4[1] == 4`) but any other number will throw an error (`0` here when `n` is odd)

-1 byte thanks to [Olivier Grégoire's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229111/98541)

Answer (score 1):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 10 bytes

```
n->n<<n%-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfmfZhvzP0/XLs/GJk9V1@h/QVFmXolGmoaRpiYXjG2sqfkfAA)

Coconut port of @xnor's trick

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 27 bytes

```lua
print(...%2<1 and...or o())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDT09P1cjGUCExLwXIzC9SyNfQ1Pz//78hAA)

Not very creative or tricky. Thanks to JS answer for reminding me about ternary operator.

Comment: Trying to take the negative of *nil* throws an error, so `...or-o` saves 2 bytes over `...or o()`

Answer (score 1):

## COBOL(GNU), 252 bytes

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.PROGRAM-ID.A.DATA DIVISION.WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
     01 A PIC 9(2).
     01 R PIC 9(2).
     01 Q PIC 9(2).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.ACCEPT A.DIVIDE A BY 2 GIVING R REMAINDER Q.IF Q IS EQUAL TO 0
DISPLAY A
ELSE
STOP RUN.
STOP RUN.
```

Please let me know if I can golf this down even more. Don't have time to explain this now.

https://tio.run/##bY4xbwIxDIX3@xUey5AI2DqaxEQWR5JzclSMLQIWBFKrSv31Tc3SY8DT82f5vXe4fdwu5nz9bo09xcprdlg5RfC846LCZklBcGvYW7QeK06ntyQbjsGUmgQDQSF3/7Ud3Ge@AITMDl5flrOJyRM2PDDNc@RHoSkHnaNcQeOVeFLb1R6WEHSLQQ2FtsjRk8Bgea1uXICGEXuoCead55J73AN21BfqtG0GGbXmv2rt93C6vJ@/mvlp5vR5PP4B

Comment: I am not familiar with this language, but can't you write that all in a single line instead of several lines?

Comment: at least, on the GNU COBOL compiler, they have to be on differing lines, otherwise I get errors.

Comment: *    GET REMAINDER AFTER DIV BY 2 INTO R

      *    MUTIPLY R BY 10000 INTO C
      *    (IF NO REMAINDER, C IS NOW 0,
      *     IF REMAINDER, C IS 10000)
    
      *    AFTER ADDING 1, C IS 1 IF INPUT IS EVEN
      *       AND 10001 IF INPUT IS ODD

      *    USING C AS A SUBSCRIPT, ONLY C=1 IS LEGIT.
      *    MOVING 1 INTO THE 10001ST OCCURENCE OF N
      *    CAUSES THIS SYSTEM ERROR--->

      * attempt to reference unallocated memory 
      *(signal SIGSEGV) ETC.

      *    MOVING 1 INTO 1ST
      *    OCCURENCE IS FINE, AND PROGRAM CONTINUES

Comment: ID DIVISION.
        PROGRAM-ID.A.
        DATA DIVISION.
        WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
             1 A PIC 99.
             1 R PIC 9.
             1 N PIC 9 OCCURS 1.
             1 C PIC 9(6).
             
  


       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
            
            ACCEPT A.
            DIVIDE A BY 2 GIVING R REMAINDER R.
            MULTIPLY 10000 BY R GIVING C.
            ADD 1 TO C.
            MOVE 1 TO N (C).
            DISPLAY A.

Comment: @RichardDonovan please clarify what you mean by these comments.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/), 16 bytes

```
1/!($argv[1]%2);
```

Divides 1 by opposite the input mod 2.
Throws a division by zero error upon odd numbered inputs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fUF9RQyWxKL0s2jBW1UjT@v///0YA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 12 bytes

```
:Y2%}_
qzp h
```

[Try it Online!](http://grok.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%3AY2%25%7D_%0Aqzp%20h&inputs=42)

Copies the input number, and if `n%2 = 0`, goes down and to the left, prints, and terminates. If `n%2 = 1`, then it hits `_`, which errors, since it is an invalid command.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org),<strike>20</strike> 19 bytes

<strike>#(/ %(- 1(mod % 2)))</strike>

```
#(/ %(mod(inc %)2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxbCoAgEAD/O8VCCLuCRN1IfGHoGqud36TPYZhxpd2vhIk@RGBACdabPiRzAoxZ@gDtWq2WvSmZg7GSuiai7S/i3PEAhbV5zOxA0UU0l3xkzdZx0Tw/)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
¥┌/
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///Q0kdTevT//zfgMuQy4jLmMuEy5TI04LK0tAQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
¥    # Modulo-2 the (implicit) input-integer
 ┌   # Invert the boolean (0 becomes 1 and vice-versa)
  /  # Integer-divide the (implicit) input-integer by this
     # (which causes division by zero errors)
     # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

J (Jsoftware.com), 7 bytes

```
   f=: 13 : '(2|y){y' NB define function f
   f                  NB. display f 7 bytes 
   =============> this is the function, it is seven characters
     ] { ~ 2 | ]
   <=============
                  NB. spaces optional
                  NB. ..and shown for clarity

   f 2                NB. test with even number
2
   f 3                NB. odd number throws error
    |index error: f
    |       f 3

NB. 2|y finds n mod 2 => 1 odd or 0 even 
NB. { use result as index into input
NB. there is only one input so 1 throws error
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 18 bytes

```python
lambda n:n/(n%2<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSHPKk9fI0/VyMZQ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Standard ML ([Moscow ML](https://mosml.org/)), 21 bytes

```ml
fun$0=0| $x=2+ $(x-2)
```

Defines a function `$ : int -> int` that throws an `Out_of_memory` exception for odd numbers. Requires the [Moscow ML](https://mosml.org/) interpreter.

```ml
- fun$0=0| $x=2+ $(x-2);
> val $ = fn : int -> int
- $ 4;
> val it = 4 : int
- $ 3;
! Uncaught exception:
! Out_of_memory
```

---

### Standard ML, 22 bytes

```ml
fn x=>x div(1-x mod 2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@1@WmKOQpmD7Py1PocLWrkIhJbNMw1C3QiE3P0XBSPO/NVdBUWZeiYZnXoleSX5wCZCTrpGmYKKpiUPGFCjzHwA)

Anonymous function that throws a `Div` exception and works in all implementations.

---

Just for fun, here are some other exceptions:

#### `Match`, 24 bytes

```ml
fn x=>(fn 0=>x)(x mod 2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@1@WmKOQpmD7Py1PocLWTgNIGdjaVWhqVCjk5qcoGGn@t@YqKMrMK9HwzCvRK8kPLgFy0jXSFEw0NXHImAJl/gMA)

#### `Bind`, 29 bytes

```ml
fn$ =>let val 0= $mod 2in$end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@1@WmKOQpmD7Py1PRcHWLie1RAEkYmCroJKbn6JglJmnkpqX8t@aq6AoM69EwzOvRK8kP7gEyEnXSFMw0dTEIWMKlPkPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 27 bytes

```
n=gets.to_i;p(n%2==0?n:n/0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWu_Ns01NLivVK8uMzrQs08lSNbG0N7POs8vQNNCEqoAoXLDIyhLAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Exceptionally](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Exceptionally), 10 bytes

```
GI}n%2=0Pn
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m702tSI5taAkMz8vMSencsGCpaUlaboWq9w9a_NUjWwNAvIgAlDxBQtNIQwA)

#### Explanation

```
GI}n%2=0Pn
G           Get a line of stdin
 I          Convert to integer
  }n        Store a copy of that value in n
    %2      Mod 2
      =0    Assert equal zero; if it's not, throws an error
        Pn  Otherwise, print n
```

If the program reaches `Pn` successfully, it loops back to the beginning, tries to read another line of input, and dies when there is no line to read.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)), 29 bytes (full program)

```python
a=int(input())
print(a<<a%-2)
```

Explanation:

```python
a=int(input()) # usual input line
         a%-2  # even numbers map to 0, odd numbers map to -1
      a<<      # part which triggers error (can't shift negative times)
print(       ) # output if no error
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTq6AIxE20sUlU1TXS/P/fEAA)

Comment: This is why the score is 29: Both lines are 14 bytes long, with the newline it's 29

Answer (score 1):

## [Re:direction](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Re:direction), 11 bytes

```
++>>
 +
v
<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0rVTcksSk0uyczP@/9fW9vOjktBm6uMy@b/f1MA)

The input number *n* is represented in the queue as *n* `>`s followed by a `v`. The loop in the first line removes two `>`s from the front of the queue (with the `+`s) and adds them back to the back of the queue (with the `>`s), exiting once less than two remain.

An odd number goes down from the second `+` and hits the `+` below it, which consumes the `>`s left in the queue, coming back to itself each time, until the queue is empty, at which point it produces an error.

An even number goes down from the first `+` with *n* `>`s in the queue, adds a `v` to re-create the representation of `n`, and then hits the `<`, which is ignored in output and points to itself to end the program.

[image: Diagram of execution paths]

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
Đ⁺2%/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRHjbuMVPX//7cEAA)

The code tries to do \${n\over(n+1)\!\!\!\!\mod\!\! 2}\$, which throws a division-by-zero error when n is odd.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 6 bytes

```
(2!)0/
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwNxMEOQDAMANB7/8KNi9LEgV8Rh9k6E6xoJT6fd3hxKKmoGgSII01/7QSAkMxOHRC9BF5kj7Wa8xu/Prm8cO3lwOthtVWyIlHfdIRrcsYSQn6OmW8F+AADHh2u)

Sets up a while-loop, testing if `2!` (i.e., mod by 2) returns a truthy value when run on the input/current value. If a truthy value is returned, it *then* attempts to calculate `0@x`, which fails with a `'rank` error, as atoms cannot be indexed. If `(2!)` returns a falsey value on the original input, nothing else is run, and the original value is returned unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 12 bytes

```ruby
->n{n/=1&~n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk/f1lCtLq/2f4FCWrRRLBeIMo79DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 19 bytes

```python
lambda x:x//(1-x%2)
```

If the number is even, `x%2` is 0 and `1-x%2` is 1, so this evaluates to `x//1` which is simply `x`, since floor dividing by 1 gives the original integer.
However, if it is odd, `x%2` is 1, `1-x%2` is 0, and this evaluates to `x//0` which raises a `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: Do you need the `//`? It seems like only integers are passed, so you can use `/` instead

Comment: @ophact The `//` is necessary to convert it back to an integer, since in Python 3, `/` always returns a float. `x // y` is effectively `int(x/y)`. Good question!

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes

```
i=input()
if int(i)&1:raise Exception
else:print(i)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2M6@gtERDkyszTSEzr0QjU1PN0KooMbM4VcG1Ijm1oCQzP48rNac41aqgCCL//78JAA)

Comment: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUaHCKlEhM02hQs0wNac4VcHg/38A for 23 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Clarion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarion_(programming_language)), 91 bytes

In Clarion, calling a function that is prototyped to return a parameter, but the body of said function does not explicitly return anything causes a runtime exception. I think I might be cheating slightly by not explicitly halting the program, but the dialog that shows after the exception occurs has a "Continue" or "Exit" button, and if you hit continue it will re-trigger the exception, giving you no choice but to terminate anyway.

The input is given as the first command-line parameter.

It's not particularly short compared to the other incredible answers here, but I like Clarion :)

```clarion
Program
 Map;f,?.
Code
 i#=Command(1);If i#%2=0;Stop(i#);Else;x#=f().
f Function
 Code
```

Answer (score 0):

### PostScript, 31 bytes

```ps
.runstdin dup 2 mod 1 eq{x}if =
```

Requires ghostscript for `.runstdin`; raises `/undefined in x` on odd input.

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```
proc f(n:int)=
  if n mod 2==1:raise Exception.newException""
  echo.n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY33QqK8pMV0jTyrDLzSjRtuRQUMtMU8hRy81MUjGxtDa2KEjOLUxVcK5JTC0oy8_P08lLL4RwlJaDy1OSMfL08iGkr0zSMNLnSNIw1IXyYLQA)

The first solution that came to mind. Rather run-of-the-mill.

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 16 bytes

```
$[n][n/(n+1)%2n]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?9w4pQw)

```
$[n][             ; a function taking an argument n
    n /           ; n divided by...
    (n + 1) % 2   ; n plus one modulo two  (error here if n is odd)
    n             ; push n
]                 ; end function, implicit return
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) (older versions only), \$ 4 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 3.29 bytes

```python
2%?J
```

This uses a bug which was fixed in v1.1.1. ATO has v1.2.1 so it will not work there.

##### Explanation

- `2%` mods the input by 2. An even number will result in `0` and an odd number will result in `1`.
- `?` is an `if` statement. If the top of the stack is truthy (`1`), run the following code:

  - `J` means `''.join` and expects a list. If it doesn't get a list, it throws an error.
  - Therefore, if the input was odd, it will throw an error.
- If it was even, it will just pass through and output whatever was input

##### Screenshots

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

## YASEPL, 11 bytes

```
=a'=b$a%@!<
```

explanation:

```
=a'=b$a%@!<              packed
=a'                      get user input and set it to A
   =b$a                  create variable B and set it to content of A
       %                 B = B mod 2
        @                if B is equal to 1, then go to point 1 (point 1 does not exist so it errors if its true)
         !<              else, print A
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 3 bytes

```
ḃ[x
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLhuINbeCIsIiIsIjUiLCIzLjQuMiJd)

If the bit parity is 0, then it just outputs the number. Otherwise it gives a "too many recursions" error

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 26 bytes

#### Main code

```lua
print(0==n%2 and n or -m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/J@nYKuQma9XlJqYoqH5v6AoM69Ew8DWNk/VSCExL0UhTyG/SEE3V/P/f2MA)

#### TIO Header

```lua
-- To read input
n = io.read()
```

---

### Explanation

We read in our input via `io.read()` into a variable `n`.

```lua
n = io.read()
```

we then write a ternary statement inside of the `print` function to test whether `n` is even or odd. If `n` is even, we pass it over to `print`, otherwise we take the negation of a `nil` global variable to throw an error.

```lua
print (0 == n%2 and n or -m)
```

Note that ternary statements in Lua come in the form of `(condition and true-expr or false-expr)`.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 19 bytes

```swift
let f={$0/(1-$0%2)}
```

If `$0` (the implicit closure parameter) is even, `$0 % 2` is `0`, `1 - 0` is 1, and `$0 / 1` is the original value. If `$0` is odd, `$0 % 2` is `1`, `1 - 1` is `0`, and `$0 / 0` ends up calling `assertionFailure(_:file:line:)`.